# select using "current_date" as criteria?

Tags: postgresql

If I've been recording data with timestamp. How can I query for today's data? Something similar to this example.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE recorded_time = current_date;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DATE_TRUNC('day', recorded_time) = CURRENT_DATE
```

should do it.